# Solr 6 streaming evaluator errors out - unknown operands found

Tags: solr, streaming, solr6

I am trying to use solr streaming with stream evalutors (6.5 version of solr). I got an error with solr streaming. Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

`select(
search(loc-1215, q=*:*, fq="LOCATION_POINTS:[100 TO 300]", fl="id,LOCATION_POINTS", sort="id asc", qt="/export", partitionKeys="id"),id,log(LOCATION_POINTS))`

i got the following error in the solr streaming. This streaming expression works fine if I remove the `log(LOCATION_POINTS)` from the **select** streaming function. I get this error `unknown operands found` as you see below. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Do I have to add any classpath settings in solrconfig.xml?

```
{
  "result-set": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "EXCEPTION": "Invalid expression select(search(loc-1215,q=\"*:*\",fq=\"LOCATION_POINTS:[100 TO 300]\",fl=\"id,LOCATION_POINTS\",sort=\"id asc\",qt=\"/export\",partitionKeys=id),id,log(LOCATION_POINTS)) - unknown operands found",
        "EOF": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

}

The field type for LOCATION_POINTS is `tdouble`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that partitionkeys is only for parallel streaming expression, not for select operation as outlined.